# How can we handle this deleted question that still has value?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787373/com-h2databaseh22-1-214-vulnerabilities/76787393#76787393), which then got deleted by the post author. However, I think it's a valid question, and one that will probably come up more often in the near future.

For those unable to see deleted questions, it's about [the disputed CVE in H2 database](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3686#issuecomment-1333917904).

I voted to undelete it. Is that correct (since the post author has deleted it) and if not, what else should I do?

Comment: I agree with you, the question may help other users, so it should not be deleted.

Comment: It's been undeleted by the meta effect, so we're good now.

Comment: In general you don't make this particular decision alone unlike your other dupe closure question, so no worries. It sounds like a typical "hide the homework" situation, except that in this case somebody might be hiding the SO post from their employer.

Comment: @Gimby That's quite the assumption. Could just be because the question had a downvote at the time.

Comment: True. Also not a good reason to delete a question, one downvote :)

Comment: This example is the exact reason a question shouldn’t be deletable by the author if the question has received downvotes and an answer without any votes for a period of time. (long enough that the answer would receive votes and the author potentially forgets about deleting the question).